# What is the best way to send data to/from iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Are there best practices for sending data to/from iOS? Should I stay away from JSON and/or XML? Also, are there well-known frameworks for this?

This is the first time I've had to send data to/from an iOS platform.

### Edit

The client/server communication is from iOS to PHP and back again. I planned on sending a REST `GET`/`POST` request and receiving the page as JSON/XML. However, I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of client-server communication?

Comment: @mrunal I added an EDIT which should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [XMLReader](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/09/11/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/) which I found online. You can use native loading and this just converts the XML into a dictionary which is much easier to deal with than using the raw `NSXMLParser`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [property lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i) which are easily readable and writable on iOS, and they are xml so you can use them in php aswell.

Answer (score 1):

See there are only two ways to pass data in client-server communication 
 1. XML and 2. JSON

If you want lightweight data loading then go with JSON data, but there are no JSON libraries provided by Apple. So, it is required to use some third party library for JSON parsing like, [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/.)

But if you want to stick with Apple APIs then go with XML parsing, for that Apple library [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this information will be useful to you.

Comment: Have you got your answer or not yet?

Comment: Please mark correct to any answer or add comments what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to stay away from JSON/XML. They're both commonly used in all kinds of web services to communicate with the iPhone (Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

The most "famous" framework for http requests is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

For JSON try [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) or I think iOS has it built in to iOS 5.
The iPhone doesn't have a DOM parser for XML but a few have been written. My personal favorite is [GDataXMLElement](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) by Google.